# I am using Sumif function in macro but the result is not getting

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have used the below code to get the answer. I m getting the result at my required location but sum is not displayed.

```
Cells(lastrow, 2).Offset(3, 1).Value = "=Sumif(L4:L" & lastrow & "," & "NEW ALBERTSONS INC" & ",J4:J" & lastrow - 1 & ")"
```

Could some one help me how to sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Cells(lastrow, 2).Offset(3, 1).Formula = "=SUMIF(L4:L" & lastrow & "," & """NEW ALBERTSONS INC""" & ",J4:J" & lastrow & ")"
```

**Some notes:**

- I'm using `"""NEW ALBERTSONS INC"""` instead `"NEW ALBERTSONS INC"`
  (you should escape your quotes when constucting excel formulas
  through vba)
- `sum_range` and `criteria_range` should have same dimmentsion, that's
  why you should use `L4:L" & lastrow` and `J4:J" & lastrow` (or `&
  lastrow-1` for both ranges)
- actually, you can slightly simplify your formula by changing `"," & """NEW ALBERTSONS INC"""` to `", ""NEW ALBERTSONS INC"""`